# page_source prints previous login page html despite browser showing a successful login using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium to log into a HikVision IP camera web client and I am experiencing an issue. The automated browser seems to successfully log in, as it loads the next page, but when I return page_source(), it shows that the webdriver is still stuck on the log in page. I have tried implementing wait/until and implicit waits for the web page to load but it does not seem to be a loading issue, as no matter how long I wait, I get the same problem.

Here is a code snippet showing how I log in:

```
user = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

# log in 
user.clear()
user.send_keys("admin")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("Snipr123")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.login-btn").click()
```

The .clear() was just to get rid of the preloaded text that was giving me issues.
After the login `click()` the automated browser successfully loads the web client, but the webdriver doesn't, since page_source() still returns the log in page.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you login using the line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.login-btn").click()
```

Yneed to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` of any of the visible element within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and then extract the *page source* as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.login-btn").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "table")))
print(driver.page_source)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```